# Twilio using access token to send SMS

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio, access-token, api-key

I keep reading in the doc that the access token can be used for services like Voice/Chat/Video, but I don't see anywhere mention sending SMS. Does Twilio exclude this functionality on purpose? i.e. my mobile app can acquire an access_token to send SMS

Comment: You need only auth token and account sid to send sms

Comment: What about this https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/keys I followed the instruction to create an Api Key, note down the secret. However, when creating a client using the account sid and the said secret, Twilio return error "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect". Why is it still looking for the AuthToken here?

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Sending SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) uses the [Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/) and to use the REST API you always need your Account Sid. There are two ways you can authenticate to the API though.

You can either authenticate with your Account Sid and Auth Token, both found on your [Twilio console](http://twilio.com/console). Then, using Node.js and the [Twilio Node module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node), you would authenticate your client like this:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
```

Alternatively, you can [generate an API Key and Secret from the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/api-keys) or you can [create an API Key and Secret using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/keys). With those credentials you can also authenticate a client, but you still need to supply the Account Sid for the resource you want to use.

```
var client = require('twilio')(apiKey, apiSecret, { accountSid: accountSid });
```

The services that use access tokens are [Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video), [Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat), [Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync) and the [Programmable Voice SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk). These are all services that have SDKs and run in the client side, either on iOS, Android or in the browser. They use access tokens because they allow the developer to authenticate users with Twilio without giving away the Auth Token or API Keys.

Comment: I am not getting 401 error if try to authenticate using apiKey and apiSecret.
Err: {"status":401,"code":20003,"moreInfo":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003"}

Comment: Are you including your account sid too, as in the second example?

Comment: It's working, It was related to my VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the message via `twilio` module with relevant information

See the example below

```
// Twilio Credentials 
var accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
var authToken = 'your_auth_token'; 

//require the Twilio module and create a REST client 
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

client.messages.create({ 
    to: "+15558675309", 
    from: "+15017250604", 
    body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?", 
    mediaUrl: "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg",  
}, function(err, message) { 
    console.log(message.sid); 
});
```

You can refer the `sending-messages` docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, but I was looking for way to send a msg using only the access token, not [sid,auth] combination.

Comment: I don't think you can send the message without `accountSid `

Comment: In this case @abdulbarik is right, you need your Account Sid and Auth Token (or your Account Sid and an API key and secret). The services that use access tokens are Video, Chat, Sync and the Programmable Voice SDKs. These are all services that have SDKs and run in the client side, either on iOS, Android or in the browser.